# Exterior angle in between two line segmenets

Tags: geometry

Say I have a line1 with points (0,0)(1,1) and line2 with points(1,1) and (2,4), what is the formula for the angle between the line segments.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The scalar product gives you the solution. If you have vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ the scalar product is:

$$v_1 \cdot v_2 = \|v_1\| \|v_2\| \cos(\theta)$$

Where $\theta$ is the angle between the two vectors. In your case each vector is the direction vector of the lines 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

To follow through with what Adolfo said, we have $v_1 = \left<\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right>$ and $v_2 = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{10}}\left <1,3 \right>$. Solving $\cos(\theta) = v_1 \cdot v_2$ now gives $\theta = \cos^{-1}\left(\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\right) \approx 26.57^{\circ}$.